# Looping back to start after each switch-case

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm looking for a way to return to the 'menu' after each case has been completed and to only exit/close the program when quit is selected. I presume a while loop would be used but I am having trouble returning to the menu and keeping all input and progress so far without restarting the program. Here's my code so far;

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class User2 {
private static Scanner in;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int userChoice;

    boolean quit = false;
    String firstName = null;
    String secondName = null;
    String email = null;
    String username = null;
    String password = null;

    do {


        System.out.println("1. Create Account");
        System.out.println("2. Login");
        System.out.println("3. Quit");
        userChoice = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());

        switch (userChoice) {

        case 1:
            System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
            firstName = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter your second name:");
            secondName = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter your email address:");
            email = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter chosen username:");
            username = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter chosen password:");
            password = in.nextLine();

            break;

        case 2:

            String enteredUsername;
            String enteredPassword;

            System.out.print("Enter Username:");
            enteredUsername = in.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter Password:");
            enteredPassword = in.nextLine();
            if (username != null && password != null
                    && enteredUsername == username
                    && enteredPassword == password)
                System.out.println("Login Successfull!");
            else
                System.out.println("Login Failed!");

            break;

        case 3:
            quit = true;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Wrong choice.");

        }

        System.out.println();

    } while (!quit);

    System.out.println("Bye!");

  }
}
```

Comment: looks reasonable OK, try debugging it.

Comment: I tried running you code locally, It seemed to be working pretty well, what is your problem?

Comment: No matter what credentials I enter when firstly creating account before attempting to login, the login always fail as if the credentials entered when creating the account aren't stored, it's like the programme restarts after each case ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `==` for String comparision use `String.equals`

e.g.

```
enteredUsername.equals (username)
```

or even

```
enteredUsername.equalsIgnoreCase (username)
```

for comparing regardless of the case of the inputted text

Answer (score 1):

I tried running your code and it wasn't letting me login after creating the account. Looking more closely at your if statement where you compare the username and password, I noticed that you are comparing strings using ==
Strings are typically objects in any object oriented language, so in java you will want to use

```
enteredUsername.equals(username)
```

and use the same method for any other strings you would like to compare. There are other string comparison methods and you can find more information on them on oracle's java documentation if you look at the string class. For the code you're working with right now, .equals will probably be the one you want to work with.